# Linux GUI for quick browsing of CMYK separations of multi-page PDF?

Tags: linux, gui, printing, color

Is there a free/open-source application that runs on Linux, where I can specify a multi-page PDF as input, then specify a page number, and then obtain a rendering of that page in color - as well as rendering of each of the cyan, magenta, yellow and black color separations? (not sure if this is called a "preflight" software for printing). Additionally, it would be great if this application could calculate the total (and which) of pages that are purely black&white (i.e. have content only on the K/black separation), and which have color content.

For a single page PDF, it is relatively easy to use `ghostscript` from the command line; as an example, with this Latex code, `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=none,draw=black,line width=2pt] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (4cm,5cm);
\draw[fill=red] (1cm,1cm) circle (1cm) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (2cm,2.5cm) circle (1cm) ;
\draw[fill=green] (3cm,4cm) circle (1cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

... and compiling it with `pdflatex test.tex`, one gets `test.pdf`, which looks like this:

[image: test.pdf]

...and it can be split to CMYK separations using:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffsep -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r150x150 -sOutputFile=test%04d.tif test.pdf
```

... which generates `test0001.Cyan.tif`, `test0001.Magenta.tif`, `test0001.Yellow.tif` and `test0001.Black.tif`, which look like this (click for full res):

[image: /tmp/test0001.Cyan.tif]
[image: /tmp/test0001.Magenta.tif]
[image: /tmp/test0001.Yellow.tif]
[image: /tmp/test0001.Black.tif]

... but clearly, this process is kinda tedious to do for a 400+ page PDF, which is why I'd prefer a GUI - even if it is just an interface to a Ghostscript command line.

Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I really needed something like this, so I managed to hack [PDF-Shuffler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/), which is a Python 2.7, GTK 2 application. I posted that patch here:

- [PDF-Shuffler / Patches / #20 Patch: add toolbar page navigation, and CMYK separations via Ghostscript](https://sourceforge.net/p/pdfshuffler/patches/20/)

... where there is a bit more info written about the patch; and with the patch, `pdfshuffler` looks like this:

[image: PdfShuffler_CMYK.png]

... so that every time a new page is selected in the top pane (either by clicking on a page thumbnail icon, or next/back buttons, or keyboard arrows, or by typing in the text entry field), `ghostscript` is called to render the separations of that page, which are eventually shown in the bottom pane - which is what I needed for "quick browsing of CMYK separations". The good thing is, seems it can handle my 400+ page document without a problem...

Well, now that it's out there, hope it helps someone...

---

EDIT: Check also the (Python 2.7) script `checkcmykpages.py`:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/sdaaubckp/code/HEAD/tree/single-scripts/checkcmykpages.py

... which is called like:

```
python checkcmykpages.py [docname].pdf
```

... and uses the `inkcov` device of (newer) Ghostscript, to generate a report noting all blank pages, all B&W pages (only K colour content), and all fully CMYK pages - and respective page numbers - of the input PDF document.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can split your pdf into multiple image files with the command:

```
convert image.pdf image_%02d.tiff
```

*Assuming you are happy with .tiff format.*

You can identify which images have colour with:

```
convert image_name.type -format "%[colorspace]" info:
```

You can separate your colour channels with the [separate](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#separate) option of the convert command, either RGB or CMYK, and others.

```
convert iamge_name.ext -colorspace CMYK -separate separate_CMYK_%d.gif
```

I am sure that you could put them together into a script or even an image processing pipeline.

ImageMagick is a free, cross platform tool.  There are ImageMagick GUIs out there but you would probably be better off with a script.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @SteveBarnes - had no idea about the `info:` thing, great to know - also great to know the alternative `convert` commands (although, I think ImageMagick uses GhostScript for PDF rendering under the hood). However, I'm still looking for a GUI tool, where I'd type or go forward/back through pages, and get the separations shown on screen... Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau You could always use GIMP for that - just be sure and open the pdf with pages as images, rather than layers - you can bind keys to the commands you need for ease of use.